# rspec expect throws "undefined method"

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am a complete Ruby newby and am playing around with rspec

I am testing a class (Account) that has this line:

```
attr_reader :balance
```

When I try to test it with this method:

```
it "should deposit twice" do
  @acc.deposit(75)
  expect {
    @acc.deposit(50)
    }.to change(Account.balance).to(125)
end
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in 'Account should deposit twice'
undefined method `balance' for Account:Class
```

I don't understand why I get the error since the attribute 'balance' exists, however I can see that it is not a method, but shouldn't rspec be able to find it anyway?

Update:
As Jason noted I should be @acc.balance, since this is what I am asserting. But I get 'nil is not a symbol' when doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be @acc.balance

```
it "should deposit twice" do
  @acc = Account.new
  @acc.deposit(75)
  @acc.balance.should == 75
  expect {
    @acc.deposit(50)
    }.to change(@acc, :balance).to(125)
end
```

Comment: The attr_reader is on an instance of the Account class, not the class itself.

Comment: Changed that (it was the way I got it originally) and now I get 'nil is not a symbol'

Answer (score 1):

i think it should be

`expect {@acc.deposit(50)}.to change(@acc.balance}.to(125`)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
it "should deposit twice" do
  @acc.deposit(75)
  expect {
    @acc.deposit(50)
   }.to change { @acc.balance }.to(125)
end
```

Please note that you need use curly braces `{ ... }` instead of parentheses `( ... )` around `@acc.balance`. Otherwise `@acc.balance` is evaluated before it is passed to `change` method which expects either symbol or block.